# How do I remove a trailing comma when an alias is involved?

Tags: sql, case

```
CASE  WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN 

      (CASE WHEN Col2=2 THEN 'a' + ', ' END) +
      (CASE WHEN Col3=2 THEN 'b' + ', ' END) +
      (CASE WHEN Col4=2 THEN 'c' END)         
END as Names
```

Names can be a,b,c or a,b, or b,

How do I remove the character "," at the end? I cannot use replace or stuff etc functions as "Names" is an alias

original Query:

CASE WHEN ht.bTax=0 then

ISNULL(CASE WHEN (r1.iOccType=2) THEN p1.SFIRSTNAME + ' ' + p1.ULASTNAME END,'') +
ISNULL(CASE WHEN (r2.iOcctType=2) THEN p2.SFIRSTNAME + ' ' + p2.ULASTNAME + ', ' END, '') +
ISNULL(CASE WHEN (r3.iOccType=2) THEN p3.SFIRSTNAME + ' ' + p3.ULASTNAME + ', ' END, '') +
ISNULL(CASE WHEN (r4.iOccType=2) THEN p4.SFIRSTNAME + ' ' + p4.ULASTNAME + ', ' END, '') +
ISNULL(CASE WHEN (r5.iOccType=2) THEN p5.SFIRSTNAME + ' ' + p5.ULASTNAME + ', ' END, '')
End AS Names

Comment: Try the FOR XML PATH technique.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/545672

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the use of an alias preclude using STUFF or REPLACE?  Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Did you looked into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839806/replace-substring-specifically-at-the-end-of-the-character-string-in-sql

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I need the answer to be a,b,c or a,b. Th point is, I am not able to remove the , from the string.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to add the comma to the end of the 'c' result exactly the same as the others then remove the last two characters from the string after the fact. I think it would be cleaner to put your first statement into a cte then select from it while cleaning up the string then:

`with cte as(
    Select
    CASE  WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 
          (CASE WHEN Col2=2 THEN 'a, ' ELSE '' END) +
          (CASE WHEN Col3=2 THEN 'b, ' ELSE '' END) +
          (CASE WHEN Col3=2 THEN 'c, ' ELSE '' END)

    END as Names
)
select SUBSTRING(Names, 0, Len(Names)) as Names from CTE`

Alternatively you can just do it inline but you'll have to repeat your string construction a second time this way.

`CASE  WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN 
    SUBSTRING(
      (CASE WHEN Col2=2 THEN 'a, ' ELSE '' END) +
      (CASE WHEN Col3=2 THEN 'b, ' ELSE '' END) +
      (CASE WHEN Col4=2 THEN 'c, ' ELSE '' END)

      ,0, LEN(
      (CASE WHEN Col2=2 THEN 'a, ' ELSE '' END) +
      (CASE WHEN Col3=2 THEN 'b, ' ELSE '' END) +
      (CASE WHEN Col4=2 THEN 'c, ' ELSE '' END)

      ))
END as Names`

Just to explain what I'm doing here:

**SUBSTRING** *(string, start point, end point)* - returns contents of string from start point (0 is beginning) and the end point

**LEN** *(string)* - returns the amount of characters in the string

By passing 0 as the start and the LEN() of the string as the last parameter, it will return the full string missing the last character (because the index starts at zero). Usually you would have to put LEN() - 1 but apparently LEN does not count the last empty character.